# Adding Wordpress to Static HTML Page?

Tags: html, wordpress

I was asked earlier today about adding WordPress to a website and was wondering if it was possible and how much work it would be.

Basically there is a static HTML page millerat.com. The owner of the site wants me to create a WordPress blog with the URL millerat.com/blog. The theme needs to look similar to the static page and the owner does not want to change the static HTML page, other than adding a navigation link to the blog.

So is this possible? How difficult would it be?

All advice on doing this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Designing a new wordpress theme could be a bit of a hassle, but overall what you're trying to do is not that difficult. What you'll want to do is simply link his static page to the wordpess blog like you would any website. The question your asking has a lot of material to be covered, but [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) should certainly get you started. Setting up the existing website is quite easy, setting up wordpress will be a bit more work. You'll need a decent grasp of PHP, HTML, and CSS to get the theme the way you'd like, but it is all definitely doable. Once again this one is a very extensive topic, but you can find the documentation for designing a wordpress theme [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Site_Design_and_Layout).

Answer (score 1):

Certainly possible.

If you're not familiar with WP, there will certainly be some learning curve.